# Phone going into Emergency calls only after USB tethering for 30 minutes

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, usb-tethering, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, emergency-calls

Since the time I started using USB tethering, my phone has been going into Emergency calls only after 30 minutes of little to no use. I find it a bother to always have to restart my hone to use calls or USB tether again.

Why is this happening? Is this a limitation of USB tethering?

This is NOT a limitation imposed by my carrier.

I am using a Sony Ericsson Xperia X10i, running stock upgraded Android 2.3.5.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This might be a limit imposed by your carrier, if you're not supposed to use tethering on your data plan. You should check with them first.

Comment: @DanHulme That was the first thing that I checked with my provider before I bought the connection. They told that they do not charge for it.